# How to Organize text data in python

Tags: python, csv

My Goal is to make a Pokimon card generator in python. I want to save data to a file, and have it orginized well.

```
pokimonfile = input('What would you like your file name to be? ')
f = open(pokimonfile, 'w')

#This Code just askes the user basic stats of the Pokimon like overall health, 2 attacks and 
the decriptions of those attacks
print("Hello! You Will Be Creating A PokeMon Card!")
Name = input("What would You Like Your Name To Be? ")
print("How Much Health Would You Like Your PokeMon To Have? ")
HP = input("")
print("What Would You Like Your PokeMon's First Attack To Be? ")
attack_name1 = input("Name of First attack? ")
attack_description1 = input("Write The Description Of Your PokeMon's First Attack. ")
print("What Would You Like Your PokeMon's Second Attack To Be? ")
attack_name2 = input("Name of Second attack? ")
attack_description2 = input("Write The Description Of Your PokeMon's Second Attack. ")
f.write(Name)
f.write(HP)
f.write(attack_name1)
f.write(attack_description1)
f.write(attack_name2)
f.write(attack_description2)
f.close()
```

The output I get is `Name100attack 11attack 22` and I wish that it would be formated so that I could easly read from the file.
Sorry that this was a ramble, please ask if I left out important info.

Comment: Instead of `f.write`, use `print(xxxx, file=f)`.  You might consider whether this should be in a simple database instead.  Or did you really want it comma-separated, as your title says?

Comment: As a side note, it would be a lot easier to do what you're doing by just typing the information into a text editor.